# Line hierarchy using indents to hierarchy using parentheses in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, indentation, brackets

I have some text that is formatted like this:

```
line01
   line01.01
   line01.02
      line01.02.01
      line01.02.01
```

But I need it to be like

```
(line01(line01.01)(line01.02(line01.02.01)(line01.02.01)))
```

Is there a way to use a text editor to change the indents to parentheses in this way?

Comment: why you have to use notepad++ for it?

Comment: I can use some other program also, if there is better solution for it.

Comment: Are all the indentations literally multiples of three spaces? Or are there tabs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Notepad++ regex Find-and-Replace functionality to complete this task with just a few unique replacements. In the "Replace" dialogue, make sure you set Search Mode to "Regular expression" and UNCHECK the box next to ". matches newline"

## The Process

Begin by reducing each indent to one space. In the example you gave, one indent is equal to three spaces, so you would start by searching for all instances of three spaces and replacing them with a single space:

**Find what:**     (three space characters)

**Replace with:**   (a single space character) (use "Replace All" button one time)

Next, find all lines that don't have any child-items and put parentheses around them:

**Find what:** `(^\s*+)(.*?)((?=($(?!\r\n)|\r\n)(?!\1 )))`

**Replace with:** `$1\($2\)` (use "Replace All" button one time)

Next, find all lines that DO have child-items and surround *the line along with its entire group of children* in a single set of parentheses:

**Find what:** `(^\s*+)(([^(].*?)(\r\n\1\s+.*)+)`

**Replace with:** `$1\($2\)` (use "Replace All" button until it doesn't find any more matches)

Finally, the last step is to remove all spaces that are between parentheses so that the final output looks like your example output:

**Find what:** `([()])\s+([()])`

**Replace with:** `$1$2` (use "Replace All" button until it doesn't find any more matches)

## Example

Sample input:

```
line01
   line01.01
   line01.02
   line01.03
   line01.04
      line01.04.01
      line01.04.02
      line01.04.03
      line01.04.04
   line01.05
   line01.06
      line01.06.01
      line01.06.02
line02
   line02.01
      line02.01.01
line03
line04
line05
line06
   line06.01
      line06.01.01
         line06.01.01.01
         line06.01.01.02
```

Output (before removing all spaces):

```
(line01
 (line01.01)
 (line01.02)
 (line01.03)
 (line01.04
  (line01.04.01)
  (line01.04.02)
  (line01.04.03)
  (line01.04.04))
 (line01.05)
 (line01.06
  (line01.06.01)
  (line01.06.02)))
(line02
 (line02.01
  (line02.01.01)))
(line03)
(line04)
(line05)
(line06
 (line06.01
  (line06.01.01
   (line06.01.01.01)
   (line06.01.01.02))))
```

Output (after removing all spaces):

```
(line01(line01.01)(line01.02)(line01.03)(line01.04(line01.04.01)(line01.04.02)(line01.04.03)(line01.04.04))(line01.05)(line01.06(line01.06.01)(line01.06.02)))(line02(line02.01(line02.01.01)))(line03)(line04)(line05)(line06(line06.01(line06.01.01(line06.01.01.01)(line06.01.01.02))))
```